# Change values of consecutive repeating letters in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I've got one Dataframe like:

```
id value block
1 a 1
2 a 1
3 a 2
4 a 2
5 b 3
6 c 4
```

And I want to change the value column to the next value based where
the series changes. Like below. The change must be defined by the 
block column.

```
id value block
1 a 1
2 a 1
3 b 2
4 b 2
5 c 3
6 None 4
```

I thought about using shift but there are different lengths of continuity in the value column.

I think this should work somehow by using cumsum to detect the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular case in which difference between consecutive block elements is 0 or unitary, you could use diff() and something like this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'block': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]})
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'None']
indexs = np.insert(np.cumsum(np.diff(df.block)), 0, 0)
df['value'] = [values[np.asscalar(x)] for x in indexs]
```

When value is already part of your dataframe, you could simply replace the values list given above by the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'value': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'block': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]})
values = np.append(df['value'].unique(), 'None')
indexs = np.insert(np.cumsum(np.diff(df.block)), 0, 0) # unchanged
df['value'] = [values[np.asscalar(x)] for x in indexs] # unchanged
```

which conducts to the same result.

Comment: This seems the right direction, but how can I assign the correct position to the values, if they are already part of the df, as shown in the example ?

Comment: You could use unique() to extract the unique elements in column value of your df, and replace the list values I used above. Check the second piece of code I added.

Comment: Thank you very much this is the perfect answer for the given case, but in fact I was looking for something more adaptable, for example, the values might be  repeating like `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']` and the block index does not have to start at 0 ... I should have pointed that out better.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way do produce what I need, but I am not happy with the code and think there should be a way to do it with nice pandas functions.
Anyway the code works also if the values are repeating and the block does not have to be continuous.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'block':[2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6], 'value': ['a','a','a','a','c','d','d','d']})

#get a list of lists with the value groups
val_groups = []
for g_id, group in df.groupby('block'):
    val_groups.append(group.value.values)

#assign the last value of a group to the next group
new_vals = None
for vals in reversed(val_groups):
    last_val = vals[0]
    vals.fill(new_vals)
    new_vals = last_val

#flatten the values
vals = [item for group in val_groups for item in group]

#assign
df['new_vals'] = vals
```